# Passing the java command exit code to batch ERRORLEVEL

Tags: java, batch-file, exit-code

I am running a batch to be executed with one of our automated process, inside this batch I am calling for a java command (application). The automated processing should see the final exit code and determine if its success = 0 or not which will be a failure. In this case it does determine that and batch resume to the next line like nothing happened.

Here is the batch

```
@ECHO Off
SET Talend_Job=%1%
E:
CD E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\
for /f "tokens=2" %%2 in (E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\Results\%Talend_Job%.txt) do (
    set  LABEL_OR_ID=%%2
    goto gotrev
)

:gotrev
echo  LABEL_OR_ID is %LABEL_OR_ID%

java -jar E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\TalendTacTasks-1.0.1.jar ^ get_task_status ^ http://dc01talndtlv01.mycompany.loc:8080/org.talend.administrator/ ^ %LABEL_OR_ID%

set exitcode=%ERRORLEVEL%
echo %exitcode%
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
exit /B %ERRORLEVEL%

----------my results log ---------------
C:\Users\Autosysdevsvc>SET Talend_Job=autosys_talend_test_with_error 

C:\Users\Autosysdevsvc>E:

E:\>CD E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\ 

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>for /F "tokens=2" %2 in (E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\Results\autosys_talend_test_with_error.txt) do (
set  LABEL_OR_ID=%2  
 goto gotrev 
) 

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>(
set  LABEL_OR_ID=1529519219417_Y6RLK  
 goto gotrev 
) 

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>echo  LABEL_OR_ID is 1529519219417_Y6RLK 
 LABEL_OR_ID is 1529519219417_Y6RLK

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>java -jar E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts\TalendTacTasks-1.0.1.jar  get_task_status  http://dc01talndtlv01.mycompany.loc:8080/org.talend.administrator/  1529519219417_Y6RLK 
ERROR: Execution Status: JOB_ERROR: Job ended with error(s) - Job Exit Code: 1

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>echo Exitcode= 
Exitcode=

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>set exitcode=0 

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>echo ERRORLEVEL=0 
ERRORLEVEL=0

E:\Operations\BatchServices\Talend\Batches\Talend_AutoSys_Integration\scripts>exit /B 0
```

Answer (score 3):

`%ERRORLEVEL%` should contain the exit code of the last command executed by your batch file - in this case, the execution of the jar file.

As seen in your output, your call to the java executable resulted in the legal return code `0`.

(Note that you do have an `echo` command immediately after your java call, but this echo call does not replace the `%ERRORLEVEL%` value).

As mentioned by both [schtever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/977649/schtever) and [Jim Garrison](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18157/jim-garrison), since your java app terminates successfully without any exceptions, the return code it returns is dependent on your java application exit code - which will be `0` if not explicitly stated via `System.exit(1)`.

References:

- [Windows Batch Scripting: Return Codes](http://steve-jansen.github.io/guides/windows-batch-scripting/part-3-return-codes.html)
- [How do I get the application exit code from a Windows command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/334879/how-do-i-get-the-application-exit-code-from-a-windows-command-line)
- [ERRORLEVEL vs %ERRORLEVEL% vs exclamation mark ERRORLEVEL exclamation mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42967840/errorlevel-vs-errorlevel-vs-exclamation-mark-errorlevel-exclamation-mark)
- [How to get the exit status of a Java program in Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/887066/how-to-get-the-exit-status-of-a-java-program-in-windows-batch-file)
- [Get exit code from a java application in batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136708/get-exit-code-from-a-java-application-in-batch-file)
- [Can one use the exit code of a Java program to detect out of disk space exceptions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31376840/can-one-use-the-exit-code-of-a-java-program-to-detect-out-of-disk-space-exceptio?rq=1)